# Convert Tensorflow array to Keras array

Tags: python, arrays, keras

I am trying to run a Keras model in which I read 88 images from a folder into a numpy array. This array should be converted into a Keras tensor so that I can work with the data in the model. I am running the following code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from keras import backend as K

current_dir = os.path.dirname('__file__')
image_names = os.listdir(os.path.join(current_dir, 'images'))
images = np.ndarray((len(image_names), 256, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
for i, filename in enumerate(image_names):
    images[i] = Image.open(os.path.join(current_dir,
                                        'images',
                                        filename)).resize((256, 256)).convert('L')
images = images.astype(K.floatx())
images *= 0.96/255
images += 0.02
images = images.reshape(images.shape[0], 256, 256, 1)

print(images.shape)
cats_q = K.variable(images)
print(type(cats_q))
print(K.is_keras_tensor(cats_q))
```

I am getting the following output

```
(87, 256, 256, 1)
<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable'>
False
```

How can I convert the output into a Keras tensor? Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks,
Andi

Answer (score 0):

You should build your model first, including an input tensor built with the correct size to handle this data, then pass the numpy array to the keras model when you call the 'fit' function.

When you build a keras model, the tensors are edges in the computation graph. You don't want to initialize it with a value, but with a size, then pass the value when necessary.

[This page](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) on the keras functional API has some good examples of this.